# ASP.Net MVC: Excluding spaces from urls with requestPathInvalidCharacters

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

In my ASP MVC site on IIS7.5, and have set a long `maxUrlLength` in order to handle urls longer than 260 characters. For this we also have to turn on `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping`.

So we have this in the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" maxUrlLength="1200" 
  relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
  requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,&amp;,*,%,:,;,\,?,%" />
```

A side-efect is that no urls that end with a space and a slash are now valid. e.g. "http://mysite.com/path/to/name /" used to throw a `HttpException` that we caught and issued a 301 redirect. But now it does not.

Is it possible to make this url behave as before? Can I specify the space character in the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` list somehow? Putting in `requestPathInvalidCharacters=" "` has no effect on spaces in urls, and neither does requestPathInvalidCharacters="&#32;".  and `requestPathInvalidCharacters="%20"` is a configuration error.

Comment: Does adding &#32; work for a space?

Comment: Ross: no, it does not. I suspect because they are encoded as %20 before that.

Comment: I ended up here trying to figure out how to set the requestPathInvalidCharacters with chevrons. Unrelated, but thanks anyways!