# ASP.NET MVC 5 dangerous Request.Path detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a fairly common issue with ASP.NET MVC 5 where it throws an exception on invalid URL characters, such as `&` and `%`.

I've tried a lot of different suggestions from other stack overflow questions, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897372/asp-net-mvc-excluding-spaces-from-urls-with-requestpathinvalidcharacters). However, adding this to my Web.config doesn't work:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,:,\,?"
                 requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Nor does adding `[HttpValidate(false)]` above my controller methods.

I found this [gem](https://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2015/02/03/rewrite-url-before-validateinputifrequiredbyconfig-throws-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client-exception/) while searching for a solution and it looked really promising, but even that doesn't work. The url requests aren't being changed with the code from that site and it makes me wonder if the problem occurs before ASP.net even gets a chance to act.

I'm trying to avoid manually encoding all my requests, but if that's what I have to do then I guess I have no choice.

Here's my stack trace if it helps:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
>
> System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9693412
>      System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered that error in a *Web-Form* application, it is often caused by special characters being passed to a Controller.  The simplest resolution, to ensure that your data is being properly encoded before hitting your Controller.  That would be the safest approach, however if you want a quick and dirty approach you can loosen the security a bit to the *Page / View* through your `web.config`.

```
<!-- Example: 'Web-Config' -->
<location path="test.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The above does the following:

> In either case, you must make two changes in the Web.config file. The
>   first change is to set the requestValidationMode attribute of the
>   httpRuntime element to "2.0". This setting makes request validation
>   occur later in the sequence of request processing events. The setting
>   is required for applications that use ASP.NET 4 and later, because as
>   of ASP.NET 4, request validation takes place earlier in the request
>   life cycle than it did in previous versions of ASP.NET.

Otherwise you could simply use the:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("...");
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("...");
```

Purpose of above:

> If characters such as blanks and punctuation are passed in an HTTP
>   stream, they might be misinterpreted at the receiving end. HTML
>   encoding converts characters that are not allowed in HTML into
>   character-entity equivalents; HTML decoding reverses the encoding. For
>   example, when embedded in a block of text, the characters < and > are
>   encoded as < and > for HTTP transmission.

You can also lookup `UrlEncode` and `UrlDecode`.

Comment: I wouldn't say this completely fixed my problem but it pushed me in the right direction. I ended up encoding my url requests, so I consider it close enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fosforus Glad it helped, yeah sadly some of the encounters are one off but usually around this approach for resolution.