# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<). Getting exception from framework pipline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting following exception on appending dodgy value in Api url.

I've tried a lot of different suggestions from other stack overflow questions, like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897372/asp-net-mvc-excluding-spaces-from-urls-with-requestpathinvalidcharacters). However, adding this to my Web.config doesn't work:

Here is error stack trace details:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).]
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +678
>      System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +52

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution in one of the stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client). It might help to resolve your issue.

or you can simply update your web.config's system.web attribute as below

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

or if you use .NET 4.0 then simple put

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i already tried above solutions. It won't fix things for me. Here is Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0